# How to make a pivot table with power query

Tags: powerquery

I have a table with number like below ,

Phone Number

123, 456, 890

123453

902, 423

so i would like to do the pivot table with can show all the phone number (delimiter is ",") and count how many time it appear in the list ? can someone assist for that?
I just have a initial step with the code below

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Phone_Number"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Phone Number", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

updated: question solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powerquery,

right click the column,

home .. split column by delimiter ... delimiter:comma, Advanced Options:rows

then right click column and group by...

use default options and hit ok

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Phone_Number"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Phone Number", type text}}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Phone Number", type text}}, "en-US"), {{"Phone Number", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Phone Number"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {"Phone Number"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: thank you very much Bro. that is what i expected.